# For number higher than x count on a specific spot in line

Tags: python, count, txt

I'm trying find a number higher than 300 in line, and want to count it.

the lines look like this:

```
181.15.193.19 - - [25/Mar/2021:07:10:52 +0100] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 2347
104.236.212.203 - - [25/Mar/2021:03:13:47 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" **302** 386
```

I'm trying to count all numbers above 300 in the spot of 302.
But as expected it will count the first 2347 if you count the whole line, which is not the spot that needs to be counted.

```
content = R_read_file()
wordcount = 0
my_word = " 300"
for line in inhoud:
    if my_word in line:
        wordcount += 1
print(wordcount)
return
```

This works but won't show all numbers above 300. It just counts the 300 and it will also count if 300 is in the second spot.

Comment: Looks like a web server log. There are probably many examples out there of parsing web server logs, and even perhaps open source libraries to do it for you properly. That said, if the HTTP response code is always the penultimate token in the input then you could just split on whitespace, retrieve the value from tokens[-2], and then parse to int, then compare to 300.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to split the line and take only the part you're going to compare:

```
line.split()
```

It will split the line where it find spaces, you can change the split() parameter for any caracter depending on the need.

Then you will look if the number you are searching for always apear in the same position, as we splited based on spaces the position means the same that the word count. Looking at your examples the number position is 8, or if you prefer -2 (reverse counting)

You will also need to be sure that the number is a integer

```
number = int(line[-2])
```

You will not need the string "my_word" since now you just need to compare:

```
if number > 300:
    wordcount += 1
```

Obs: If you also want to count the numbers that are equal to 300 just put >= in the IF statement.

I realy hope that I helped, sorry any english error, I still learnig :)

Comment: Can't quite figure out what to put where. This is what I have now.

Not sure where to put the line.split()

content = R_read_file()
wordcount = 0
number = int(line[8])
    for line in inhoud:
        if number >= 300:
                wordcount += 1
print(wordcount)
return

Answer (score 0):

Answers is based on assumption that you can filter/loop the string row and want to count occurrence of numbers above 300

solution:

```
from collections import Counter

string_data = """181.15.193.19 - - [25/Mar/2021:07:10:52 +0100] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 2347 
104.236.212.203 - - [25/Mar/2021:03:13:47 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" **302** 386"""
# split data 
split_data = string_data.split(" ")
# alue to check against
VALUE_ABOVE = 300
# filter number above 300
values = [value for value in split_data if  value.isnumeric() and int(value) > VALUE_ABOVE]

print(values)
print(dict(Counter(values)))
```

**Output:**

```
['2347', '386']
{'2347': 1, '386': 1}
```

Comment: This would work, but I want it to not count the second number. Just the first 3 digit number.

Comment: kindly share some expected result

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem like this:

```
    with open('D:/file.log', 'r') as f:
    lines: list[str] = f.readlines()
import re
count = 0
for line in lines:
    found = re.search(r'(\s[3-9][0-9][0-9]\s)', line)
    result = int(found.group(0)) if found else ""
    if found:
        count += 1

print(count")
return
```